# jar file cant run after compiling by netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jar, jvm, jna

I developed an application in java (video player by vlcj),
all conditions:
my windows: 8.1
jdk: 8.1 (update 11)

it has been run successfully in netbeans(fine) but when created .jar file is executed it reported a long error that summarized below

The required native libraries are named "libvlc.dll" and "libvlccore.dll". 
it is not possible for a 64-bit Java Virtual Machine to load 32-bit native libraries.
what is the solution?
plz help comrades.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the x64 version of the JDK. Go to sun Java and download and install the x86 version and set it up in the systems environment settings like you did for the x64 version.

Answer (score -1):

I was Facing Same Problem today But I try Running it  as Administrator. Some UAC Permission are in my Java Program.

Even output Jar File not running after compiling.I convert it in An exe file with Launch4j. And run it As Administrator. Its Running.